# How to run a bat file from a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

Is there any way to run a batch file from a function written in `plpgsql`?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible directly from PL/PgSQL.

You can do so only by providing a helper function in an untrusted PL like PL/Perlu or PL/Pythonu that in turn runs the batch file.

In Python you'd use something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION exec_system_cmd (command text)
  RETURNS return-type
AS $$
  import os
  import sys
  os.system(command)
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Or you could be a bit more sophisticated and use the `subprocess` module to pass an array of arguments instead, so you don't have to worry about escaping `%`, `>` and other special characters in the command-string.

Obviously `exec_system_cmd` should only be executable by the superuser, and if possible, you should instead write a more specialized function that doesn't let the user run any command they like.

While this is *possible*, that doesn't make it a good idea. I agree with Erwin that it's better to have an outside helper program using `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` to run commands when required.

Answer (score 2):

No direct way, for security reasons.
Look into [`LISTEN` / `NOITIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-notify.html) to trigger executables outside the DB.